# Did a rabbit bite Justice David Souter?

Tags: united-states, ethology

In a panel discussion titled *[HLS in the World | A Conversation with Six Justices of the U.S. Supreme Court](https://youtu.be/_EeU6Lo_i7I?t=5817)* [partially transcribed at [Harvard At 200: Justices Look Back On Their Law School Days — And Beyond : NPR](https://www.npr.org/2017/10/31/561041265/justices-look-back-on-their-law-school-days-and-beyond-at-harvards-200th)], [Justice Stephen Breyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Breyer) told an anecdote about retired [Justice David Souter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Souter) at the 1h36m58s mark:

> STEPHEN BREYER: While he was an active member of our court, he's walking in the woods somewhere, a rabbit jumped on his back and bit him in the neck.

Was David Souter bitten by a rabbit?

Comment: I wanted to link to a related question I could have sworn we had about [1979 encounter of then President Carter and a rabbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_Carter_rabbit_incident), but I must have imagined it.

Comment: @Oddthinking both were attacked by rabbits

Answer (score 3):

According to the 25 July 1990 article [Killer rabbit redux](http://www.chicagotribune.com/news/ct-xpm-1990-07-25-9003020539-story.html) *Chicago Tribune* :

> David Souter, President Bush`s choice for the U.S. Supreme Court, has at least one thing in common with Democrats. He was attacked by a killer rabbit. Jimmy Carter, the last Democrat to be president, once was saved from an attacking bunny by the Secret Service. The judge was nipped while hiking in the mountains of New Hampshire

Comment: Now this rabbit attack was before Souter was appointed to the Supreme Court.  The one in the question was during the time he was active on the Supreme Court.  Two attacks?  Or Breyer got the timing wrong in his story?

Comment: @GEdgar I guess he has the timing wrong.  Breyer and Souter were both also simultaneuously judges for the Court of Appeals for the 1st circuit.